# How do Google Chrome or other iOS browser apps replicate "backForwardList"

Tags: ios, swift, browser, wkwebview

I need to make a web browser which should keep WkWebView's backFowardList even after app is closed so it really works like Safari, Google Chrome or like other proper browser apps.

However, WkWebView's property backFowardList is a readonly property. 
How did Google Chrome, Opera or other proper browser apps replicate this function?